# Jackson can't serialize Spring proxy object

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, jackson, cglib

I'm using `@ConfigurationProperties` to create an object like this:

From application.yml

```
myObject:
  field1: field1
  field2: field2
```

And I have these classes defined:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyObject {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyObjectConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(value = "my-object", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
    public MyObject myObjectBean() {
        return new MyObject();
    }
}
```

I then inject the bean where I want to use it.  If I just print it out, `toString()` works fine.  In the debugger, if I look at the object, it looks like this:

[image]

I don't know how the Spring magic works

If I try to serialize with Jackson,

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

I get a huge stack trace that seems to start with an IllegalStateException.  I can't figure out what it's complaining about

But if I create a constructor in MyObject that takes another MyObject and just copies the fields,

```
MyObject nonProxy = new MyObject(myObject);
```

I end up with what I think is a non-proxy version of the object, which I can then serialize.  But this requires that I know which objects are proxy objects, which sort of defeats the purpose.  Is there a way to get Jackson to properly deal with these proxy objects?

### Update

I put together a simple application using Spring initializer, but in that case, it works fine.  Here is the main Springboot class:

```
@Component
public class Startup implements InitializingBean {

    private final MyObject myObject;

    public Startup(final MyObject myObject) {
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("*** myObject: " + myObject);
        System.out.println("*** class: " + myObject.getClass().getName());

        try {
            final String s = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObject);
            System.out.println("*** json" + s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


*** myObject: MyObject(field1=field1, field2=field2)
*** class: com.example.demo.config.MyObject
*** json{"field1":"field1","field2":"field2"}
```

What could possibly be different in my application that would cause Spring to proxy this object?  Note that in my application, when I print out the class of MyObject, I get

```
*** class: com.torchai.service.skeleton.configuration.MyObject$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f9d27e0
```

Comment: I can’t see any reason for `MyObject` to have been proxied. Can you share all the code that’s necessary to reproduce the behaviour you have described?

Comment: My understanding is that Spring creates a proxy when it creates an object using `@ConfigurationPropertie`s.  I pretty much posted all the code.  If you inject the MyObject bean and inspect it in the debugger or try to serialize it with Jackson, you should see the same thing I'm seeing.

Comment: You are right.  I put together a simple app from Spring Initializr using my same classes and it works fine.  So what would cause Spring to proxy this object in my application?

Comment: Proxies are created for a variety of reasons (transaction management, method-level validation, etc). You could debug your application with a breakpoint on `org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(AdvisedSupport)` to determine what's triggering the proxy's creation.

Comment: Thanks.  This confirmed that it is indeed creating a proxy, but I'm not sure how to tell why.  The isProxyTargetClass() flag is on and hasNoUserSuppliedPRoxyInterfaces() also returns true, which are the conditions for creating a proxy, but I'm not sure what that means in a practical sense or what I can do to change it.

Comment: Hopefully the stack at the time the method is called and/or the advice that's added to the proxy will help to identify why the proxy's being created.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find or how to interpret the 'advice'.  Does that refer to the CGLIB$CALLBACK methods I posted in my screenshot above?  Any help appreciated

Comment: Yes. It should be apparent from the state of those callbacks. The stack should hopefully make it apparent too. I would be much easier to help if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah, that was my original intent, but it seems my minimal example works.  So I need to figure out what's causing it to break or change behavior

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say why it worked/didn't work. However, to get rid of the serialization error involving `$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$`, I did something like this;

```
@JsonSerialize(as = MyObject.class)
public class MyObject {
  public String getField1() { return field1; }
  ...
}
```