# Inject spring bean @ConfigurationProperties with toJson method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

**application.yaml**

```
mail:
  hostname: host@mail.com
  port: 9000
  from: mailer@mail.com
```

I have a Spring Bean which read properties from yaml and i want to inject them in necessary places.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
public class ClientProperties{
    public String hostName;
    public int port;
    public String from;
    public String time = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper; 

    @JsonIgnore
    public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    }
}
```

`@Autowired private ObjectMapper mapper` As far as I know, this type of injection is not recommended. How to do it correctly?

This injection into another config **failed**

```
@Configuration
public class SolisCloudConfig {
    @Value("${external.api.baseurl}")
    String baseURI;
    @Bean
    RestClient restClient(RestClient.Builder builder, ClientProperties properties) throws Exception {
        return builder
                .baseUrl(baseURI)
                .defaultHeader("mail-header", properties.toJson())
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restClient' defined in class path resource [com/connector/config/SolisCloudConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestClient]: Factory method 'restClient' threw exception with message: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.experimental.connector.config.ClientProperties$$SpringCGLIB$$0["$$beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestClient]: Factory method 'restClient' threw exception with message: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.experimental.connector.config.ClientProperties$$SpringCGLIB$$0["$$beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.experimental.connector.config.ClientProperties$$SpringCGLIB$$0["$$beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])
```

```
2024-03-08T00:14:11.791+02:00  WARN 17207 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restClient' defined in class path resource [com/connector/config/SolisCloudConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestClient]: Factory method 'restClient' threw exception with message: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: experimental.connector.config.ClientProperties$$SpringCGLIB$$0["$$beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current method will result in json string - `"something"`. The problem is that you turn into json the string representation of your class.

To fix it, you should just provide the *current instance*, **not** its' stringified value.

```
public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
}
```

This will result in:

```
{
  "port": 9000,
   other props
}
```

Additionally there is no need to create new instance for ObjectMapper everytime you call `toJson()`. You can use a static instance, or you can autowire the configured one - since you are using spring boot, it's highly likely that you already have one configured as bean (jackson is used by default in spring boot).

```
@Setter
@ToString
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
@JsonSerialize(as = ClientProperties.class)
public class ClientProperties {

  public String hostName;
  public int port;
  public String from;
  public String time = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

  @JsonIgnore
  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  @JsonIgnore
  public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
  }
}
```

The serialization error was caused by spring proxying the component. You can fix that by adding - `@JsonSerialize(as = ClientProperties.class)`, as shown in [Jackson can't serialize Spring proxy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71608233/jackson-cant-serialize-spring-proxy-object).

Do not forget to `@JsonIgnore` object mapper to exclude it from the serialized result.

Comment: I updated description can you please check

Comment: @Romillion Check the update for fix of the serialization error. Your additional question about the *correct* way to inject ObjectMapper is unrelated to the current one, you should remove it and ask that in a different question, or this one may be closed due to lack of focus.

Comment: @Romillion Still, you can use constructor injection for `ObjectMapper` only. Keep in mind that you are already using setter injection for the properties, so unless you inject them through the constructor as well, that would be partial fix.

Answer (score 0):

For this helper method:

```
public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this.toString());
}
```

the object should be used, instead of the string version of the object.  (And that helper method might need to be ignored to avoid endless recursion.)

```
@JsonIgnore
public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
}
```

Similar for that `getDigest()` method.

I'm not sure if it will impact the creation of the json string, but it looks like there are no getter methods on those private fields.  Why aren't those fields final, with getter methods?  How is this configuration class even used?

Also, with Jackson on the classpath, `ObjectMapper` will be an available Spring bean, so that bean should be injected where needed instead of creating a new instance everytime.

Comment: I updated description can you please check